# How do I *automatically* create a frequency histogram of individual alphanumeric values in Excel?

Tags: excel

Basically, I want to do a histogram count of the number of NSF Fellowships awarded by undergraduate institution (which is Column C). How do I do this from this data table? (taken from https://www.fastlane.nsf.gov/grfp/AwardeeList.do?method=sort&page=25 )

[image]

I'd like to do it completely automatically - without having to manually insert the names of each and every university. A short Excel workflow is fine.

Comment: By "completely automatically" do you mean literally a one-click solution, or would you be willing to settle for a short Excel workflow (that does not involve manual transcription)?

Comment: I'm willing to settle for a short Excel workflow without manual transcription. Thanks. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Formula - Count the frequency of text values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955872/excel-formula-count-the-frequency-of-text-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 5):

if i understand correctly, you want to insert a pivot table + column chart with data from column C as both rows and data (using count) ...

[image]